# Constraint to a column which stores only foreign key of other tables?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table which stores history of different entity objects. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS History
(
    "id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "reference_id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "description" Text,
    CONSTRAINT "History_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
```

Should there be any constraint for reference_id column which will store id from other tables ? If yes, then how to add that.

Comment: What you are looking for is declaring a [Foreign Key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-fk.html). Since your table already exists also see [Alter Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) Add *column constraint*.

Comment: @Belayer, I am not looking for foreign key, we can apply foreign key constraint when it may store a particular table's primary key. Whereas, in my case the reference_id column can store primary keys of any table. Lets say there are TableA (primary key colA), TableB (primary key colB), now this history table's reference_id may store colA or colB or any other table's primary key which will be defined later on in future. Is there any other suitable constraint ?

Comment: There is no such constraint. You may be able to create a trigger function, but seems that at a minimum you need a column containing the table name being referenced and then dynamic SQL to validate the the reference exists.  .